# Hierarchical prediction using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, document-classification, text-classification

I'm pretty new in R, and I couldn't find any information about a package who can do the following: supposing that I have a set of data (for instance, different text documents), which can have several classes.

For example, a datum could be a Sport, a Sport with Ball, a Sport without Ball and a Car. I'd like to be able to predict to which category the data belongs, considering that I may not hit that the datum is a Sport with Ball, but I'd be happy if I correctly predict that it's a Sport.

Which package can provide this kind of stuff? Some examples would be useful, if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make your explanation and example clearer? Are you looking for multi-label classifier such that each datum can belong to multiple classes simultaneously? Why are you calling it hierarchical?

Comment: It's not exactly multi-label. I called it hierarchical, because I have to classify my datum inside the following "leaves" classes: rec/autos, rec/motorcycles, rec/sport/baseball, rec/sport/hockey, sci/crypt, sci/med. Notice that I'd like to be able to predict that some datum is, for instance at least from rec class and try to advance further in the rec subclasses. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you modify your question to show where the hiererachy is? And maybe you are interested in SVMstruct (http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_struct.html) which is not R but I am not aware of any structured clasification tools in R. Maybe someone else has pointers?

Comment: Look into package [`tm`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf). There is a tutorial on how to do various types of classification with that package [here](http://web.letras.up.pt/bhsmaia/EDV/apresentacoes/Bradzil_Classif_withTM.pdf).

Comment: @jlhoward there is no example of hierarchical classification in that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any specific packages in R that can do hierarchical classification. So there are two options:

- Use the C API SVMstruct http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_struct.html. Programming this in R from scratch will be quite some work.
- Build your own hierarchical classifier system. In the top-down case you will have a    multi-class classifier for each level, e.g. rec vs sci and motorcycles vs sport etc. You will use the top classifier and use its prediction to choose next classifier. The data you feed in to train a classifier with a node is the union of all data in the subtree rooted at that node.

For details read e.g. http://jmlr.org/papers/v6/tsochantaridis05a.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, @kap. I'll try to perform your second suggestion, let's hope everything goes fine